# How to connect Tab Controls

Tags: c#, winforms

my winForms app has a tab control which consists of two tabs (tab1 & tab2). In tab2 data is fetched in a datagridview fron a database(Product infomations).
In tab1, I've a combobox [sales analyse]which makes a user to select an option.
I now want to get access to tab2 from tab1 on cb selection, displaying me a regional sales information from the data in tab2 datagrid.
Is it possible? I don't really know wher to start

tab1 image 
[image]

tab2

[image]
Expectation:

if the combobox in tab1 is selected, it should then look through the datagridview in tab2 where the (regions) North, East, West ect are and then  sum the sale 13, sales 14 .. and display in the textBoxes respectively.

Comment: To access anything you just need a reference to it. If your TabPages are basically static you can add the references in any way you like. But as they are all in the same form anyway(?) they already see each other. So there is nothing to do at all..! - This is not true if the TabPages contain Usercontrols.Do they? If so, please update qour question!

Comment: @TaW. An example will be great for a start. The only user control is the `combobox` for the selction.

Comment: _The only user control is the combobox_ Probably not. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294974/usercontrol-vs-customcontrol-in-c-sharp) for the difference between CustomControls and UserControls! If it is a CustomControls  (aka subclass) there is no problem. If it is a UserControl after all, you would have to expose its fields in some way, best via Properties..

Comment: What is `cb selection` ? An event? The selectionChanged of the ComboBox? Or a CommandButton?? Please edit your question to be precise and complete!!

Comment: @TaW. Thnx. I do understand u now. It's a UserControl. `cb selection` the selectionChanged of the ComboBox. That means if the combobox is selected, it should then look through the datagridview in tab2 where the North, East, West ect is and sum the sale 13, sales 14 .. and display in the textBoxes respectively.

Comment: Yes, I have seen it. But we really should be clear about this: Is the ComboBox __really part of a UserControl__??? A UserControl is a __container__ for other controls. A comboBox cannot __be__ a UserControl! You can derive a custom version of ComboBox, ie sublaclass ComboBox, resulting in a CustomControl.. - There is a reason why I insist on this being cleared up: The controls inside a UC by default are not accessible from the outside. So the solution will be a little different..

Comment: Have you really renamed the SelectionChanged event?? Why? The only good reason to do such a thing is when you have either several events all triggered by the same handler or several controls all using the same event..

Comment: Ok. I thought it is a UserControl because I draged and droped the `combobox` from tools and then activated the selectionChanged event in properties to generate the code logic. `private void cbAnalyse_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cbAnalyse.SelectedIndex == cbAnalyse.FindStringExact("Sales anylse"))
            {
                                          
            }}`
Would be glad if you can help me implement my intension

Comment: OK, two more questions: 1) what is in the combobox? Data or things like 'sales analysis' and other commends? 2) just what is missing? You seem to have all those (terribly many) textboxes already in place nad ready to display all the data? Are you missing code to copy the data from the DGV or just the sums or both?

Comment: @TaW.Sorry for the delay.I  was no more in the Uni. There are no data in the `combobox`. Haha the `terrible textboxes` should display the sum for example if `combobox` item is selected, in the background it should go to tabb2 and look through DGV and find the Region and the sum the corresponding value and then display them in the assigned `textBoxes` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your controls all sit in one Form their methods can all reference each other without any additional help.

So you can write in the `SelectedIndexChanged` of the `ComboBox cbAnalyse`

```
cbAnalyse_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   if (cbAnalyse.SelectedItem.ToStringndex == "Sales Analysis"
   {
        someTextbox1.Text = ColumnSum(yourDataGridView, someColumn1) + "$";
        someTextbox2.Text = ColumnSum(yourDataGridView, someColumn2) + "$";
   }
```

This uses a small helper function, which sums up all values from one column in a DataGridView:

```
decimal ColumnSum(DataGridView dgv, int columnIndex)
{
    decimal sum = 0m;
    for (int row = 0; row < DGV.Rows.Count; row++)
       if (DGV[columnIndex, row].Value != null) sum += Convert.ToDecimal(DGV[1, row].Value);
    return sum;
}
```

Folks often run into problems when they need to refer to controls that are **not** sitting in either the same Form but in a 2nd, 3rd etc Form. Or when they are part of a `Usercontrol`, which is a custome container for holding controls.

In both cases those controls are by default private members of the other Forms or of the UserObject.

In these cases one needs to create some kind of public accessor to them, usually by a Property. And in the case of Forms, one also need to provide a reference to the other forms, often stored when opening them.

In this case, the 2nd Form often also needs a back-refrence to the 1st Form; this is often pass in in the constructor.

But in your case none of these complications matter. All you need is the patience to wire up all those TextBoxes ;-)

**Update:** As you also seem to have a problem getting the intermediate sums and need to allow for repeating regions in the rows of Tab 2, you also want to use a function that will calculate with a where clause:

```
decimal ColumnSumWhere(DataGridView dgv, int columnIndex, string region)
{
    decimal sum = 0m;
    for (int row = 0; row < DGV.Rows.Count; row++)
       if (DGV[columnIndex, row].Value != null) &&
          (DGV[regionColumn, row].Value.ToString() == region)
               sum += Convert.ToDecimal(DGV[1, row].Value);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thanks TaW. I will check on your suggestion and give you a feedback if I succeed or not. I hope I will succed. Schönen Tag noch ;-)

Comment: Hi TaW. Unfortunately I couldn't. The problem is that I think I need a `where clause` to sum up the attributes i need. I think your sample sums the whole column right?  Back to my DVG in the column sales13, the values for north are 2x 800. So the txtBox for north shd display 1600

Comment: _in the column sales13, the values for north are 2x 800. So the txtBox for north shd display 1600_ Um, no. Do you mean 800+200=1000? Is it correct to have reapeating rows in the Tab2? (This was not there when I wrote my answer, I believe..) If so, What about the rows with the '?' in the Tab1? Not also repeating, I hope..?!

Comment: @TaW.Guten Tag! Thanks it was a great help.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, whenever you change the value in sales analyze combo, the tab page containing data grid should should be activate.
You can set the selected index of the tab control to the the data grid tab, and it should work

```
this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;//Index of data grid tab
```

Comment: No tab2 shouldn't be activated. if the `combobox` is selected, it should then look through the `datagridview` in tab2 where the North, East, West ect is and sum the sale 13, sales 14 .. and display in the textBoxes respectively.  I have updated my question

Comment: @James: In that case, you must have some datasource of your grid for example data table. Just find the record from the datasource where "Region" is equal to combo selected value, and once you have got the record, find the respective values from "Sales13, 14  and 15" respectively.