# Re-using the code in OnPaint(), from one class to another

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `PictureBox` which resides in `Class A` (essentially a single tabpage), which has all of its methods `OnPaint()` defined inside there.

I want to declare another `PictureBox2` which resides in `Class B` (another tabpage). So technically all of its `OnPaint()` code will be the same, just that the name changes.

My question is that which would be a better way: To copy the entire `OnPaint()` in `Class A` into `Class B`, modifying the `PaintBox` that it refers to; or is there a better way to avoid the double work? (Like calling the `Class A` `OnPaint()` from `Class B` with a parameter?)

Comment: You might also consider repackaging your code into a [`CustomControl` or `UserControl`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322451/what-is-the-difference-between-user-control-custom-control-and-component), where you can reuse more than just the `OnPaint` handler

Comment: Would inheriting from the same base class solve your challenge? Or a static method that resides somewhere?

Comment: There is not enough context here to answer the question. For example, why do you want a second class? What will be different about the two `PictureBox` subclasses? For that matter, why are you subclassing `PictureBox` if you're just overriding `OnPaint()`? Why not just subscribe to the `Paint` event? If you really need two different subclasses, and you just want to share the code in `OnPaint()`, why not just create a helper class that contains that code, and call it from each subclass?

Comment: I think Peter is right: create the painting method in a 3rd class and pass in the sendr/picturebox and the e.Graphics from the Paint events of both classes PBs'. If needed you can add more params..